# Android Studio 3.0.1 unable to resolve dependency error

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

Hello I am new to `Android Studio`.

Just installed latest `3.0.1` on windows 7.

I am getting `gradle` dependency error and I am not able to even start my first basic project.

I have tried each and every method i found on this site or anywhere on internet but nothing worked.

Please help me, The errors are.

```
Error:Error:Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugAndroidTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve junit:junit:4.12.
Error:Error:Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugAndroidTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.squareup:javawriter:2.1.1.
Error:Error:Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugAndroidTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve javax.inject:javax.inject:1.
Error:Error:Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugAndroidTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve org.hamcrest:hamcrest-library:1.3.
Error:Error:Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugAndroidTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve org.hamcrest:hamcrest-integration:1.3.
Error:Error:Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugAndroidTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:2.0.1.
Error:Error:Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve junit:junit:4.12.
Error:Error:Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@releaseUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve junit:junit:4.12.
```

[image]

[image]

Thank you.

Comment: post your Gradle files contents here please. (build.gradle for both Project and Module)

Comment: Can you post whole gradle file here or visit [Migrate to Android studio 3.0](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/gradle-plugin-3-0-0-migration.html)

Comment: Looks like you might be enabled 'offline mode' in settings of android studio or you might not connected to internet. please check that. And also check you are using latest gradle version.

Comment: I have edited the post and added 2 images with both gradle codes

Comment: No I have tried both enabling and disabling offline mode. Installed the software thrice with all sdk packaged . I have 42mbps internet connection. Gradle version is latest 3.0.1  . I have tried everything I found on internet sources . Very much frustrated .

Comment: Please help me Please

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same issue, i just disabled my antivirus (avast) before relaunching the rebuild process.

Answer (score 0):

1. In your Settings > Build,Execution,Deployment > Gradle, Make sure
   `offline work` is **not** enabled and also make sure you are using
   the default gradle wrapper (Recommended) in the same menu.
2. Now in your top level Build Gradle file just delete the following

   ```
   maven {
      url "https://maven.google.com"
   }
   ```

   You don't really need that.
3. Now in your app level build gradle file change all the `compileOnly`
   to `implementation`
4. sync gradle
5. Clean project

Comment: Thank you for answering but it didn't work.Offline work is disabled.

Comment: Then maybe you should try creating a project from scratch and see how it goes? Also make sure your PC has internet access and you are not behind a firewall that's blocking Android Studio

Answer (score 0):

When we update the Android Studio, we will get these type of issues.
I am solving the following way. may be it is not good solution but it is working good.

1. after updating the Android Studio, its better to update SDK tools (some times its mandatory also).
2. Once we update both, then create a sample project. It will fetch the default settings of current updated settings. 
   may be we will get the some test directory issues. 
   so you should resolve it : copy these urls in the application level gradle file

   ```
   allprojects {
   repositories {
       maven { url 'http://repo1.maven.org/maven2' }
       maven { url 'http://jcenter.bintray.com' }

   }
   ```

   }
3. once the project created successfully. Then we need to check the classpath in the application level gradle file

   ```
    dependencies {
       classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
     }
   ```

we should use same classpath in the existing projects.
4. we also need to check "gradle-wrapper.properties" under the gradle folder under the project structure.
Here we need check the following line

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.1-all.zip
```

we should use the same line the existing projects.